# Java Regex Removing empty paragraphs

Tags: java, regex

Basically I need to remove all the empty paragraphs from a text. The following does not seem to work...

```
String postLevel = content.replaceAll("<p>\\s*</p>", "");
```

Any thoughts as to why?

Non-ascii characters got into the string somehow.....I removed them and this worked. LOLz

Comment: Define "doesn't work". That works fine for me.

Comment: That should work just fine... When you say it doesn't seem to work - what are the results? Can you try `<p>[^<]*</p>` to confirm at least removing all paragraphs work?

Comment: I think maybe there is non-ascii character between the paragraph tags somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this expression instead:

```
<p>\\s*</p>|<p/>
```

This would take care of `<p></p>` and `<p/>` empty paragraphs as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "<p> </p>";
s = s.replaceAll("<p>\\s+</p>","");
System.out.println("Result: " + s);
```

Output:

> Result:

I suspect your problem is that's not what your input looks like. You also will have the problem that regexes are incredibly bad at parsing HTML and it's generally a beat-your-head-against-the-wall effort to try.